# Java 8 JAR file not executing correctly in command prompt

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cmd, arguments

I have a simple Java program which takes two integer program arguments from IntelliJ IDEA and then prints the sum of the two arguments to the console. When I run the program with IntelliJ, it executes fine. I created a JAR file of my program called `FirstProject_jar3`(which was my second attempt at trying to get this to run in command prompt) and attempted to execute it in command prompt with `-classpath FirstProject.jar org.firstjavaproject.tutorial.TwoSum`, but I am getting an error that says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at org.firstjavaproject.tutorial.TwoSum.main(TwoSum.java:5)`which I know means that my program arguments are not configured. However, I do have two integer arguments (3 and 5) configured using the IDE. Any ideas why it isnt working? See the code, file paths, command prompt screen and IDE configuration screen below. Let me know if you need any more details to help me out.

`TwoSum.java`

```java
package org.firstjavaproject.tutorial; // imports package

public class TwoSum { // start class "TwoSum"
    public static void main(String[] args) { //define the method
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); //define variable "a" with the first integer in the program arguments
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //define variable "b" with the first integer in the program arguments
        int sum = a + b; //add variable "a" and "b"
        System.out.println ("a + b = " + sum); //print out the sum of the integers in a statement
    }
}
```

`output from IDE`

> `a + b = 8`

> `Process finished with exit code 0`

`file paths in IntelliJ`

[image: file paths in IntelliJ]

`cmd screen`
[image: cmd screen]

`IntelliJ configuration screen for TwoSum`
[image: IntelliJ configuration screen for TwoSum]

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:
Thank you to those who provided answers! It makes sense now that I would need to input the numbers into command prompt for my code to work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run under command prompt, you don't have the arguments configured in Idea. Try

```
java -classpath FirstProject.jar org.firstjavaproject.tutorial.TwoSum 3 5
```

with the two values at the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run this code through your IDE there will be a specific location within the IDE where you can apply Command Line Arguments for testing purposes. These testing arguments are obviously absolutely neccesssary for your code to function so as not to generate an Exception. You obviously know this.

In the real world however, away from the IDE, when your application is compiled those values you applied as Command Line Arguments are no longer part of the overall picture of things...after all, they were only there for testing. Now those values need to be supplied as **real** Command Line Arguments as others here have nicely pointed out.

```
java -jar "C:\Path_To_My_JAR_File\FirstProject.jar" 3 5
```

Not relevant in your case but did you notice how the path is enclosed in quotation marks (**"..."**). This is just in case the path contains one or more whitespaces in it. Any single Command Line Argument that will contain one or more whitespaces should be encapsulated within quotation marks otherwise that argument will be interpreted as one or more arguments since Command Line arguments are in fact separated by... whitespaces.

Acquiring the Command Line Arguments is one thing but ensuring that those arguments are actually valid is another. Generally, pushing out an exception is fine and is explanatory enough but sometimes it may be necessary to take over and output a little more or prevent an exception altogether. Validating the Arguments provided gives you that control. As a simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //define the method
    /* Here, sum is declared as double type because this code can
       accept ay number of both integer and floating point values
       to sum up.        */
    double sum = 0.0d; 
    
    /* This StringBuilder object is used to build the equation that
       will be displayed within the Console Window. It will contain
       'only' supplied valid arguments and only if there is more than
       one argument.                  */
    StringBuilder equation = new StringBuilder("");
    
    // What Command Line Arguments were suppied...
    switch (args.length) {
        // If no arguments were suppied!
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Result is 0 since no arguments were supplied to sum up.");
            break;
        case 1:
            // If only one argument was supplied!
            if (args[0].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                sum += Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
            }
            System.out.println("Result is " + sum 
                    + " since only one argument was supplied to sum up.");
            break;
        default:
            // If more than two arguments were supplied. 
            /* The code below allows for two or more Command Line Argument 
               values to be supplied and processed accordingly.         */
            for (String value : args) {
                /* Validate that the supplied argument is indeed an integer 
                   or floating point value either signed or unsigned.    */ 
                if (value.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                    // It's valid so parse it as Double type...
                    sum += Double.parseDouble(value);
                    // Build upon the equation for display...
                    // --------------------------------------
                    if (!equation.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        equation.append(" + ");
                    }
                    equation.append(value);
                    // --------------------------------------
                }
                else {
                    // Argument is found to be invalid so skip it. Inform User.
                    System.out.println("Skipping the supplied argument (" + value 
                                    + ") since it is not a valid numerical value!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result is: " + sum);
    }
    
    /* Print out the equation that generated the 
       sum of the values supplied but only if more 
       than one argument was supplied.            */
    if (args.length > 1) {
        System.out.println ("Equation:");
        System.out.println (equation + 
                (equation.toString().isEmpty() ? "" : " = ") 
                + sum); 
    }
}
```

Once compiled into a `.jar` file you might start it something like this:

```
java -jar "C:\Path_To_My_JAR_File\FirstProject.jar" 3 5 122 12.67 8.8 11
```

And the output in the Console Window should look like:
Result is: 162.47
Equation:
3 + 5 + 122 + 12.67 + 8.8 + 11 = 162.47

If no argument(s) were supplied:

```
java -jar "C:\Path_To_My_JAR_File\FirstProject.jar"
```

The output would be:

```
Result is 0 since no arguments were supplied to sum up.
```

And, if only one argument is supplied:

```
java -jar "C:\Path_To_My_JAR_File\FirstProject.jar" 8.13
```

The output would be:

```
Result is 8.13 since only one argument was supplied to sum up.
```

If one or more **invalid** arguments were supplied within the list of arguments:

```
java -jar "C:\Path_To_My_JAR_File\FirstProject.jar" 3 5r 122 12.67 8.u8 11
```

The output would be:

```
Skipping the supplied argument (5r) since it is not a valid numerical value!
Skipping the supplied argument (8.u8) since it is not a valid numerical value!
Result is: 148.67
Equation:
3 + 122 + 12.67 + 11 = 148.67
```

Comment: This is a bit too long than what I was hoping for an answer but thank you for the example.